# Understand the XPath expression

Tags: regex, xml, xpath, xslt

I want to understand the below XPath expression

```
fn:replace ($var,concat('^.*',fn:replace('.','(\.|\[|\]|\\|\||\-|\^|\$|\?|\*|\+|\{|\}|\(|\))','\\$1')),'')
```

I understand
`\` denotes an escape character
`|` denotes OR
`.` denotes any single character

But I am confused with the use of `\$1` here. What is it referring to?

Answer (score 0):

`$1` is a [back-reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html).

The goal of the expression is to replace any regex meta-character (`.`, `[`, `]`, and so on) with an escaped version of that character.

Comment: To clarify, that's what the inner fn:replace() call does. The output of the inner fn:replace should then be a regular expression, which is used as the second argument of the outer fn:replace() call. The whole thing could probably have been achieved more easily by using the "q" regex flag - though I think that needs XPath 3.0.